# No login screen after changing ram

Tags: boot, ram, bios

I installed 4GB RAM before, and today I installed 8GB of RAM from another company. With these two together, everything works fine but the Ubuntu login screen is not showing. I must use only one of them for it to show. Is there any way to fix this issue, even by changing BIOS settings?

I am currently using this motherboard: [ECS] DURATHON2 A320AM4-M3

Comment: Is there only a problem with the login screen, or does Ubuntu not boot at all?

Comment: If Ubuntu is booting, please show me the output of RAM section. Use "sudo lshw" in terminal.

Comment: i don't know its name but lots of texts that shows while in boot are printed very well. (I disabled simple booting by editing grub config). I think that OS boot well. But screen freezes when GUI shown. Something like ubuntu background shows in bottom right in window and freezes.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using and is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: You weren't clear. Did you ADD 8G RAM, or REPLACE the 4G with 8G? How much total RAM do you think you have? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I added 8G ram to 4G. It has 12GB ram. It's impossible to access console to type commands.

Comment: It's much better to install RAM in equal size/type pairs, so that you can take advantage of memory interleaving. If you computer only works with either the 4G or 8G RAM is installed, your two RAM sticks are probably different, and incompatible, specs. Recheck what you've got... and lets check the output from my previous comment. Use one RAM at a time if that's required to get this info. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll probably miss them.

Comment: Also... check your BIOS to see if it sees all 12G.

Comment: Yes. It says 12288MB.

Comment: Are you working on getting the requested info? Can't help without it. Also... remember... Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll probably miss them.

Comment: @heynnema  free -h said total 10gi used 700mi free 9gi, I luckily could startup ubuntu(didn't do anything. just reinstalled ram for few times.) but it says my total ram is 10 gb

Comment: @heynnema https://pastebin.com/YvkQnQpm
It's full text. Can you help me fix ubuntu says it's 10gb?

Comment: Are you saying that re-seating the RAM fixed the problem? It shows 10G because your BIOS is probably set to give 2G to the internal video card. Are you using internal video, or some other PCI video card?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92236/discussion-between-dhkim0800-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 0):

Check your RAM specs, and BIOS version...

**Check your RAM specs...**

[image]

**Check your BIOS version...**

In `terminal` do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to see what version BIOS you have now. Compare it to this...

[image]

Go to http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_DOWNLOAD/EN/Motherboard/A320AM4-M3%20-LL-V1-DO-0A-RR-/Socket%20AM4/DCID/BIOS to download the latest BIOS.

**Update #1:**

Re-seating the RAM fixed the problem. System is working now. Amount of RAM showing to Ubuntu is only 10G, as 2G is assigned to internal video card. This value can be adjusted in the BIOS.

Comment: Ram is compatible. But do you know how to update the bios? There are no Windows in this computer.

Comment: What BIOS version do you have? It looks like you can update it from your BIOS/UEFI menu. Check the motherboard docs for details. Manual is available at the same link as the BIOS. Also, please supply the answers and output from my previous comment.

Comment: In fact, I updated the BIOS this February.